# John The Ripper: "No such file or directory"

Tags: john-the-ripper

I am using John the Ripper jumbo release on Windows:

1.9.0-jumbo-1 64-bit Windows binaries

[image]

I am told that there MIGHT be 2 different passwords in the zip file.
To avoid problems, I should pick only 1 file.
To do that, I should use the `-o` option.

If I use the following...

```
zip2john.exe myfile.zip -o vooab.vtv > hash.txt
```

... then it tells me `! -o : No such file or directory`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please look at the usage. Options must be given before the zip files, not after as you did.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you very much! Then it's wrong here (or it's different on another OS?) https://github.com/openwall/john/issues/3464

Comment: I think you have to use sth like `-o myfile.zip\VM_M\vooab.vtv` as it's shown in the warning

Comment: This is a basic use question that is answered by reading the documentation.